# Python absdiff performance on submatrices

Tags: python, performance, image-processing

I am calculating the sum of the absolute difference of two matrices (representing two images, in RGBA with uint8 type) to see how similar they are to eachother. I've stumbled upon a weird efficiency problem, where calculating the distance on submatrices (specifically, I'm only considering only the RGB channels) takes roughly 5 times as much as doing it on the whole matrices.
Here's my code:

Firstly, I load two images using OpenCV and convert them in RGBA (since when they load they are BGR) like this (the paths are specified before):

```
template_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(template_path, flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
big_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(big_image_path, flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
```

Then I calculate the similarity this way (the 1000 loops are only to exagerate the time that it takes. I do 1000 loops in all the tests so it shouldn't make a difference):

```
first = template_image[:,:,0:3]
second = big_image[0:200, 0:400,0:3]
t = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    numpy.sum(cv2.absdiff(first, second))
print(f'elapsed time: {(time.time() - t):.3f} s')
```

Running this multiple times, it gives elapsed times that swing between 1s and 1.2s

This weirded me out because before restricting it to the RGB channels it used to take much less. In fact, with this code:

```
first = template_image[:,:]
second = big_image[0:200, 0:400]
t = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    numpy.sum(cv2.absdiff(first, second))
print(f'elapsed time: {(time.time() - t):.3f} s')
```

the average elapsed time is roughly 0.25s

This itself is enough to weird me out as why should it take 5 times as much to do technically less calculations?

---

I've also tried a different piece of code to check the similarity only on the RGBA and this weirds me out even more:

```
first = numpy.zeros((200, 400, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)
first[:,:,:] = template_image[:,:,0:3]
second = numpy.zeros((200, 400, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)
second[:,:,:] = big_image[0:200, 0:400,0:3]
t = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    numpy.sum(cv2.absdiff(first, second))
print(f'elapsed time: {(time.time() - t):.3f} s')
```

Now this code takes on average 0.19s. It makes sense that it takes less than the one calculated on RGBA as it is less calculations, but why would it take so much less than the other one done only on the RGB channels?
I've specified the `dtype=numpy.uint8` because that's the type of the images as I read them with OpenCV, and otherwise it would create matrices in float64 type which (understandibly) takes much more time.

What's the reason behind this weird behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: In the slow example try `first = template_image[:,:,0:3].copy(); second = big_image[0:200, 0:400,0:3].copy()`. That should remove any strides.

Comment: Oh so the strides are what's causing the performance issue? Thanks! Didn't know that